# Указать кодировку в заголовке письма

Tags: php

Приветствую всех

```
$to = $massiv["to"];
$subject = $massiv["subject"];
$message = $massiv["message"];
$mailheaders = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: mysite.ru <no-reply@mysite.ru>";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: mysite.ru";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $mailheaders);
```

Примерно так отправляю письмо. Можно ли как то указать кодировку в заголовке письма?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем вопрос понятен, в mailheaders уже указана кодировка.
Кодировку заголовка можно вот так задать:

`$subject = '=?koi8-r?B?'.base64_encode(convert_cyr_string($masssiv[subject], "w","k")).'?=';`

Comment: Скажем без кодировки письма не корректно доходили на mail.ru. С кодировкой проблема прошла. А вот в Опере (браузер), есть свой встроенный почтовый килент. Вот ему письма приходят с непонятным заголовком и понятным текстом. Вот и хочу заголовок поправить.

Извиняюсь, первый раз вижу такую конструкцию по изменению кодировки. Эта команда изменяет кодировку на koi-8 ?

Comment: Суть в том что часть почтовых клиентов не понимают в заголовке кодировку win-1251, поэтому её нужно перевести в koi8. Предложенный вариант 100% рабочий. Однако, в koi8 нельзя передать, наприрмер, символ №, например, чтобы сформировать заголовок типа: "Оформлен заказ №121".

Почитайте мануал http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail здесь есть всё чтобы отправить сообщение в правильной кодировке.

Comment: Всё они уже давно прекрасно понимают, хоть UTF8, хоть cp1251. Нужно только правильно указать чарсет, и не отправлять Subject без кодирования.

Answer (score 1):

Письмо же в text/html, значит, как обычно:

```
$message = "<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"
</head><body>
...";
```

Comment: @klopp это для заголовка не поможет. В самом письме у меня так и сделано. Конкретно заголовок интересует

Comment: Тогда с самого начала: что такое по-вашему "заголовок письма"? Если имеется в виду поле Subject, то всё как сказал @Зоркий. Гуглить по словам mime subject encoding, первые же ссылки подробно расскажут.